# Spring security and EJB 3.0 security

Tags: spring-security, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am experiencing an issue while calling an EJB from a Spring Web application that uses Spring Security (under Glassfish 3.2.1).

I have configured the Web application to authenticate using Spring Security against JDBC.

The user returned by authentication process is correct and has all the correct roles associate with it.

Unfortunately when I call the EJB, the user is still correct however it does not have any role associate, therefore the execution cannot proceed as it should.

It seems that the Spring security context is not "reflected" in the EJB SessionContext.

The Spring security xml looks like:

```
      <global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/>

  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" realm="spring-realm" >

      <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/resources/*" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="hasRole('backoffice')" />

      <form-login
              login-page="/login.html"
              default-target-url="/index.html"
              always-use-default-target='true'
              authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
              username-parameter="j_username"
              password-parameter="j_password" />
      <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />

  </http>

  <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider>
          <password-encoder ref="md5PasswordEncoder" />
          <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="jdbc"
                             users-by-username-query=
                                     "select administrator_name, administrator_password, administrator_enabled from administrator where administrator_name = ?"
                             authorities-by-username-query =
                                     "select administrator_name, security_role_name from vw_administrator_security_role where administrator_name = ?"
                             role-prefix="" />
      </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="md5PasswordEncoder"
              class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
  </beans:bean>
```

In the EJB I am using the **SessionContext ctx** and I can verify that **ctx.isCallerInRole()** returns false.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?
Could you please suggest me how to solve it?

Thanks